# Is it possible to read CPU cache hit/miss rate in Android?

Tags: android, cpu-cache

Is it possible to read CPU cache hit/miss rate in Android?

Comment: For some extra +1's, answers could explain what this is and why it is important.  Maybe I live in a cave, but I haven't heard about this until now.

Comment: @user432209 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache This explains the problem far better than I personally can.  Section 4 deals with cache misses.

Comment: If you're looking for an in-depth read on CPU caches, take a look at chapter 3 of this: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf ... if you just want something short (that focuses specifically on ARM, as a bonus) see: http://arunkumarv.blogspot.com/2010/08/arm-memory-organisation.html

Comment: I found the solution here:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4237.html
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4237.html
still don't know how to read the performance counters of L2 cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the developer docs, you can use [android.os.Debug.startNativeTracing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#startNativeTracing%28%29) to get information about cache misses, if you are running the kernel in qemu.

[This page](http://www.seangri-la.com/cgi-bin/moin.cgi/Android_Development) is not very organized, but there is an excellent section on using startNativeTracing() that you should take a look at if you're having trouble figuring it out: http://www.seangri-la.com/cgi-bin/moin.cgi/Android_Development